# Python - can you "refresh" a variable to re-initialize with new sub-variables?

Tags: python, string, declaration

Say i want to declare a string for my entire class to use, but that string has a part that might change later. Is it possible to only have to declare the string once, and "refreshing" it later?

Example:

```
substring = ""
my_long_string = f"This is a long string using another {substring} in it."
    
def printMyString(newString):
    substring = newString
    print(my_long_string)

printMyString(newString="newer, better substring")
```

Can i adjust this code so that in the end, it prints out `This is a long string using another newer, better substring in it.`, *without* declaring the long string again later on?

My only guess would be something like this:

```
substring = ""

def regenerate_string(substring):
    return f"This is a long string using another {substring} in it."
        
def printMyString(newString):
    print(regenerate_string(newString))

printMyString(newString="newer, better substring")
```

But i want to ask if there possibly is a built-in function in Python to do exactly that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `f-string`, declare the template string with place holder `{}` and use `format()` where necessary

```
my_long_string = "This is a long string using another {} in it."

print(my_long_string.format("newer, better substring")) # This is a long string using another newer, better substring in it.
print(my_long_string.format("some other substring")) # This is a long string using another some other substring in it.
```

You can insert as many substrings as you want that way

```
string = "With substrings, this {} and this {}."
print(string.format("first", "second")) # With substrings, this first and this second.
```

You can also use variables

```
string = "With substrings, this {foo} and this {bar}."
print(string.format(foo="first", bar="second")) # With substrings, this first and this second.
print(string.format(bar="first", foo="second")) # With substrings, this second and this first.
```

Comment: Would also be a good idea to show the keyword form of `.format()` with multiple `{foo}`s and `{bar}`s.

Comment: im 99% sure someone tested it once and f-string is more efficient than .format() - are you sure? why else would i not use f-strings? but i will try this if it solves the issue, thanks

Comment: @Ythotha74 well if you use `f-string` the only way to replace the variable in it is to create a new string using replace and the value of that variable, you can't change a variable in it.

Comment: @Ythotha74 f-strings are meant more for "static" cases where the brevity and readability of the code is more interesting. Your use case calls for `.format()` more.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because you declare `my_long_string` as the return value from the function `f"This is a long string using another {substring} in it."`, **not** the function itself.

If you want to use the substring like you intended to in your example, you would need to declare `my_long_string` to be `lambda : f"This is a long string using another {substring} in it."`, which would change return values when `substring` changed.

But like Guy said, `my_long_string.format(substring)` is perfectly reasonable.